# Akka pattern for processing lots of events

Tags: scala, design-patterns, actor, akka

I'm looking for a design pattern using Akka for the following problem. Say that I have a big file with lots of logged events. I start an actor (Master) that processes the file and for each event sends a message to a pool of actors for processing (parsing, transformation, etc, ...) and they send the result back to the Master for serializing the end result of each event. Processing events is independent of each other events.

So my first thought was to use a `Future.traverse` call and await the whole list. But I'm worried about performance since processing events is a fine grained task and creating that big list of Futures could be a memory hog and a performance drain.

Is there any pattern where I can use the `?` operator (fire and forget) but at the same time be acknowledged of the time when all events have been processed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd have the processor-actors request batches of work from the master and acknowledge each batch when it's done.

Comment: So compared to my solution you would break into batches? Would you make a "BatchMessage" ?

Comment: I probably wouldn't, I'd send an EndOfBatch-message

Comment: Yes, by reversing the flow of data, workers ask for work instead of the master pushing work helps in the design

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with Actors, I like reasoning on the way they are implemented:

- Actors processes messages from their mailbox
- The mailbox is a fifo queue
- An actor is guaranteed to have finished processing a message before processing the next one.

You have two solutions that comes to my mind, which are definitely not the only one:

- Record on the sender side how many messages you route, and having the processor actors sending a confirmation when they are done. Maybe the FMS will help you in that.
- Hierarchical organize the routing of messages and the "ack" mechanism as well. This looks to me the most elegant pattern.